# I have Python errors

Tags: python, attributeerror

I am having several python errors in this code and I need help with the code. I'm fairly new to python so I have trouble figuring this out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sandbox/stats.py", line 74, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/sandbox/stats.py", line 66, in main
    "Mean of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]: ", mean(range(1, 11))
  File "/root/sandbox/stats.py", line 25, in mean
    list.range()
AttributeError: 'range' object has no attribute 'range'
```

this is the error I keep getting.

This is my code

```
def median(list):
   if len(list) == 0:
       return 0
   list.sort()
   midIndex = len(list) / 2
   if len(list) % 2 == 1:
       return list[midIndex]
   else:
       return (list[midIndex] + list[midIndex - 1]) / 2

def mean(list):
   if len(list) == 0:
       return 0
   list.range()
   total = 0
   for number in list:
       total += number
   return total / len(list)

def mode(list):
   numberDictionary = {}
   for digit in list:
       number = numberDictionary.get(digit, None)
       if number is None:
           numberDictionary[digit] = 1
       else:
           numberDictionary[digit] = number + 1
   maxValue = max(numberDictionary.values())
   modeList = []
   for key in numberDictionary:
       if numberDictionary[key] == maxValue:
           modeList.append(key)
   return modeList

def main():
   print 
   "Mean of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]: ", mean(range(1, 11))
   print 
   "Mode of [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]:", mode([1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4])
   print 
   "Median of [1, 2, 3, 4]:", median([1, 2, 3, 4])

main()
```

I don't know how to actually fix it.
I've tried to quick fix and replaced == with the is operator but nothing worked

Comment: Can you explain what you think the `list.range()` line means?

Comment: What do you expect `list.range()` to do?

Comment: I'm not sure on what it does or what to expect. I'm a beginner trying to do an assignment and my teacher isn't of much help to me. I figure it would list the range/mean. When I ran the code in VS code it said  I had an error with the list.sort() line of code. @SilvioMayolo

Comment: It sounds like you're programming using guess-and-check, which is just not going to work. You need to make sure you understand what Python is doing with your code. `list` in your example is not the type `list`, it's a local variable you declared to shadow that. And `.range()` is looking for a method *called* `range` on the type `type(list)`, which presumably doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print something make sure you are using opening brackets:

```
   print("Mean of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]: ", mean(list(range(1,11))))
   # print("Mode of [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]:", mode([1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4]))
   print("Median of [1, 2, 3, 4]:", median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

In order to make your median code working you should cast the midIndex to integer type:

```
midIndex = int(len(list) / 2)
```

I rewrote you mean function a bit:

```
def mean(list):
    length = len(list)
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum = 0
        for n in list:
            sum += n
    return sum / length
```

I called this function with a list made with range:

```
list(range(1,11))
```

I am not sure what you want to achieve with your mode function. But perhaps you have had some help now to try this one yourselve.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -2):

```
list.range()
```

modify

```
range(list.start,list.stop,list.step)
```

len(list) / 2 is float

```
 midIndex = len(list) / 2
```

modify

```
 midIndex = math.ceil(len(list) / 2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWZ16.png)

Comment: Where do you expect `list.start` to come from?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).